# Bypass "Daemon is inhibited"

Tags: linux, partitioning, mount, gui, gparted

**When [GParted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GParted) is open**, I cannot use the GUI to mount, unmount, or do other operations to partitions.  The GUI (includes GNOME, KDE, and Xfce) complains that the "*daemon is inhibited*".

[image: Palimpsest cannot read SMART data, in case you can't see the image that's supposed to be here...]

However, if I use the terminal, I can do all those operations normally as if GParted was not open.

My question is **how can I disable or circumvent the restrictions that GParted places on the GUI?**  As a desktop user, this was confusing at first and not desirable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Run this command each time a process prevents other programs from controlling devices:

```
sudo killall udisks
```

You can now manage devices with your user-level interface while having GParted open.

**Note:** This only has a one-time effect and does not prevent the `udisks --inhibit` from locking again.

---

`root` is the only user that can inhibit all polling.  This is a security measure so that while the super user is working with dangerous tools like GParted, a normal user cannot mess things up between refresh intervals of such tools.

<sup><sub>Source: [udisks Reference Manual](https://linux.die.net/man/1/udisks)</sub></sup>

Comment: Finally accepted this solution. It works well, but if anyone else has a better way, post it as an answer, and I'll accept it.